# Construct a pointer in C from an address

Tags: c, pointers, mpi

I initially get an address of a pointer from another processor and I need a pointer that points to the items at that address.  Don't worry too much about the MPI_Recv, just know that I am getting information from another processor. So I have:

```
MPI_Recv(&a, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  

c = a;
printf("%d",c[0]);
```

Why does this give me a segmentation fault?  I have tried allocating memory for c as well before setting c = a and it will still seg fault.

Comment: Search virtual memory address first.

Comment: Another very relevant detail: Which operating system?

Comment: OS: Linux. This is a parallel application and should be processor I believe

Comment: @hyde If I am running my application on a cluster, I would assume each node would have its own processor.  However each node may have several processes.  I think this is the correct distinction, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @thepristinedesign Ah clustering, `mpi` tag added now, even. There it might or might not be right terminology to say *processor*, I'm not familiar enough to say it one way or another... Deleting my comments above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each process has its own separate [virtual address spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Pointers from one process are meaningless in the context of another process.

You have several options:

1. Use [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) instead of processes.
2. Use [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).
3. Send the actual data rather than just a pointer.

Only the last option is viable if your processes can reside on different computers.

Comment: With shared memory one still has to provide relative addresses instead of direct pointers as the shared memory segment may be mapped at different virtual addresses in each process.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it misses *MPI shared memory*.